# Merging workbooks in OAD (Oracle Analytics Desktop)

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics

Is there any way we can merge multiple canvases from different workbooks into a single project/workbook?

If we import a .dva file into OAD, it functions as a new separate workbook.
I wanted to use individual canvases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste canvases from one workbook to another. There is no "merge". Just click on the little arrow left of the canvas name to open the menu, choose "Copy Canvas", then navigate to the new/different workbook and repeat the process, choosing "Paste Canvas" this time.